# Map from ICollection<EFEntity> to ICollection<ViewModel> to ICollection<Object> with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

What is the best/easiest way to configure AutoMapper to map `ICollection<DomainModel>` to `ICollection<ViewModel>` to `ICollection<object>`?

I have a DomainModel which looks like this:

```
public class DomainModel
{
    ICollection<EFEntity> Data;

    //other stuff
}
```

I want to map this DomainModel to an MVC ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModelWithCollection
{
    ICollection<object> Data;

    //other stuff
}
```

I need `ICollection<object>` because I use the following View:

```
@model ViewModelWithCollection
<table>
    @foreach(object x in Model.Data)
    {
        Html.Partial("PartialView", x)
    }
</table>
```

For each concrete ViewModel there exists a PartialView like this:

```
@model ViewModel
<tr> <!-- Render specific View Data --> <tr>
```

When I use

```
AutoMapper.Map<DomainModel, ViewModelWithCollection>(source, target);
```

AutoMapper just makes something like this:

```
object target = (object)EFEntity
```

which of course won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some hours of searching i found out that the thing i want to achieve is called Mapping Inheritance: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance

So the solution to my problem is

```
AutoMapper.Map<DomainModel, ViewModelWithCollection>();

AutoMapper.Map<EFEntity, object>()
    .Include<EFEntity, ViewModel>();

AutoMapper.Map<EFEntity, ViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I had what appears to be the same problem.

I had my domain model:

```
public class Client
{
 public int ClientId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

And my View Model:

```
public class ClientProfileViewModel
{
 public int ClientId { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<ContractProfileViewModel> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my Mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientProfileViewModel>()
      .ForMember(c => c.Contracts, options => options.MapFrom(c => c.Contracts));

Mapper.CreateMap<ClientProfileViewModel, Client>()
      .ForMember(c => c.Contracts, options => options.MapFrom(c => c.Contracts))
```

Comment: Is the `ICollection<Contract>` property of the `Client` domain model missing its name (**Contracts** perhaps?) in your sample code?

Comment: Good spot, I've fixed this now. That wasn't part of the issue, just a typo on my part when writing the above.